# How to handle CSC/AVS with Paypal's Transparent Redirect?

Tags: paypal

I would like to use Transparent Redirect (feature of Paypal Payments Pro package) to handle checkout. PayPal documentation (excerpt below) says that when using Transparent Redirect, PayPal will not handle checking AVS and CSC, leaving that task to me.

Is it really necessary to turn off "AVS" and "CSC" as described in the documentation?

If it is necessary, then what is a practical way to handle this? If I don't perform AVS and CSC checking, then it seems it would result in more fraudulent charges. Maybe it violates PayPal TOS too. Are there 3rd party web APIs that perform the service?

From Paypal's "Transparent Redirect" documentation:

> You will need to provide your own  receipt and email along with AVS
>   and CVV2 checks. • Security Settings (AVS & CSC) must be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which page in the documentation you're looking at, but it sounds like it's misleading you.  There are actually a couple different places you can fall in to with Payments Pro.

In most cases, when you're approved for Payments Pro you get full access to Fraud Management Filters (or what used to be known as Risk Controls.)  By default, these settings are configured to accept pretty much any payment whether AVS or CSC match or not.  It simply gives you full control.

With full control you have the ability to setup your account to simply accept payments where AVS or CSC fail (which again is the default), or you could set it to automatically decline payments where these fail, or you could set it to accept the payment, but flag it and send you warnings about it.

These settings are available in your PayFlow Manager settings or PayPal profile depending on version of Pro they got  you on.

In some cases, if you have bad or not much credit, they may approve you for Payments Pro, but they'll actually set your Fraud Filters up for you so that AVS and CSC must match in order to approve the payment.  In these cases they won't give you access to adjust these settings on your own.

So basically, you just need to look for your Fraud Filters and configure them to suit your needs.

Comment: Andrew, thanks! I've updated the question based on your answer. Note that the Paypal documentation (excerpt added to question) is specifically saying that AVS and CSC must be disabled in manager for Transparent Redirect. Can you can confirm that this is not the case?